# Java if statement bug

Tags: java

This is my code:

```
    while(valid==false)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter a reference number which is two letters followed by three digits and a letter(B for business accounts and N for non business accounts)");
        ref = keyboard.nextLine();       

        if (ref.length() != 6)
        {
            System.out.println("The reference number must be 6 characters long");
            errors = errors + 1;
        }            

        if ((Character.isDigit(ref.charAt(0))== true) || (Character.isDigit(ref.charAt(1))== true))
        {
            System.out.println("The first 2 characters must be letters");
            errors = errors + 1;
        }

        if ((Character.isDigit(ref.charAt(2))== false) || (Character.isDigit(ref.charAt(3))== false)||(Character.isDigit(ref.charAt(4))== false))
        {
            System.out.println("The 3rd,4th and 5th characters must be numbers");
            errors = errors + 1;
        }

        if ((!ref.toUpperCase().endsWith("B"))||(!ref.toUpperCase().endsWith("N"))) 
        {
            System.out.println("The 6th character must be either B(for business accounts) or N(for non business accounts) ");
            errors = errors + 1;
        }

        if (errors==0)
        {
            valid=true;
        }
    }

    return ref;
```

When running the program using a reference: aa123b (an accepted state) it displays:"The 6th character must be either B(for business accounts) or N(for non business accounts)"

It should not display anything and instead should return the String.

Comment: If it helps everything within the while statement works other than the "if((!ref.toUpper...." it does not work for 'b','B','n' and 'N'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the last character must be either `B` or `N`, then the condition in your code is wrong.
Instead of

```
(!ref.toUpperCase().endsWith("B")) || (!ref.toUpperCase().endsWith("N"))
```

it should be

```
(!ref.toUpperCase().endsWith("B")) && (!ref.toUpperCase().endsWith("N"))
```

You need `and` instead of `or`.
Read it like this: *"If last letter is not B **and** last letter is not N, then error"*.

Comment: Thank you very much! I get the logic now I was treating the statement as "_If the last letter is not B or N_"

Comment: @andrewfenny you should familiarize yourself with [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws)